# Can two people within the same organization work on the same project at the same time

Tags: google-app-maker

We are developing an application using google app maker. A colleague and i want to work on different module of the same google app maker project. How is it possible to merge changes she makes with the my copy?

Thanks,
Maria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App Maker support collaborative editing. So just share the application with the colleague and work on it together.